# OleDbException Unhandled (No value given for one or more required parameters.) -Visual Studio 2010

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, oledb

I am making a project on Railway reservation system in which I want the user should have access to his booking history . The following code access records from two tables in the database . When I run this code for only one table ( accessing records from one table ) , it works fine but when I run this code for two tables , it gives me an error saying OleDbexception was unhandled ( No values given for more required parameters ) at

da.Fill(ds, "Table2")

I know this line is wrong , because it is only for one table but I don't know how to do it for two tables . Please help ! Thank you !

Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form12

```
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\AMEN\Documents\Railway.accdb"
Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim tables As DataTableCollection
Dim source1 As New BindingSource

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MyConn = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select P.Tnumber, P.Name , P.Age ,T.PNR_Number,  P.Train_Name , P.SeatNo , P.Berth , P.Coach_Number , T.Starting_Point , T.Destination , T.Departure , T.Arrival , T.Fare From Table1,Table2 Where P.Train_Name = T.Train_Name and P.Phone= TextBox1.Text ", MyConn)
    da.Fill(ds, "Table2")

    Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two tables in your query you want to join together. I'll proceed on the premise Table1 is T and Table2 is P in your query. Just change that if it's reversed.

With that said, try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using cn = New OleDbConnection(connString)
        cn.Open()
        Using da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT P.Tnumber, P.Name , P.Age ,T.PNR_Number,  P.Train_Name , P.SeatNo , P.Berth , P.Coach_Number , T.Starting_Point , T.Destination , T.Departure , T.Arrival , T.Fare FROM Table1 T INNER JOIN Table2 P ON P.Train_Name = T.Train_Name WHERE P.Phone='" & TextBox1.Text & "'", cn)
            Dim dt = New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

It's also a good idea to employ Using blocks for disposable resources like connections and data adapters.

Comment: Thanks for replying . It says OLeDbException unhandled at da.Fill(dt) . Also says No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: Sounds like you may have an issue with the query syntax. If you can copy and paste the query into a query tool, substituting a test value for the actual value in the WHERE clause, and see what it says. Are your tables named Table1 and Table2?

Comment: Yes, my tables are named Table1 and Table2